# Is gettimeofday able to deal with daylight saving time?

Tags: c, time

What would it happen if the time change happens while I'm measuring an interval, for example:

```
gettimeofday(&start, NULL);
 system("./anotherProgram");
 // during the execution of another program, time changes
 gettimeofday(&end, NULL);
 elapsed = (end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) + (end.tv_usec - start.tv_usec) / 1000000.0;
```

Will `elapsed` be increased/decreased of an hour?

Comment: From the manpage (http://linux.die.net/man/2/gettimeofday): _The time returned by gettimeofday() is affected by discontinuous jumps in the system time (e.g., if the system administrator manually changes the system time). If you need a monotonically increasing clock, see **clock_gettime(2)**._ I think you want a monotonically increasing clock for interval measurement. Btw. do you know the program `time` (http://linux.die.net/man/1/time) ?

Answer (score 0):

On Unices, `gettimeofday` always measures time linearly from [the Epoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_epoch). Local time conversion and DST is unrelated to that and won't affect it at all.

I don't actually know how this is on Windows these days, however. It used to be that Windows actually changed the hardware clock when a DST switch happened, which I would assume would affect what `time` and `gettimeofday` returned as well, but I can't really say I know Windows all that well. Neither do I know whether that's still the case.

If anything, you may have to watch out for [leap *seconds*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second), but they are far rarer to begin with (not to mention they won't affect your program as much), and if I'm not mistaken, `ntpd` and the like smooth them out over some time. I may be wrong about the latter, however.

If you want an actual, monotonically increasing time, you should consider using `clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, ...)` instead.

Comment: The "official" ntpd does not smooth leap seconds out; it makes the clock discontinuous, which has led to all sorts of nasty software problems. Busybox ntpd is much better-behaved; it smooths them out, and actually sleeps for long intervals at a time so that the cpu can sleep like it should.

Comment: @R..: Thanks for clearing that up. It should still be noted, however, that even if `ntpd` does smooth out leap seconds, you still have a clock that's going either too fast or too slow.

Answer (score -2):

You want to measure the time delay during the execution. 
When you write any time in code `elapsed = (end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) + (end.tv_usec - start.tv_usec) / 1000000.0;` it will show the same delay while execution of `system("./anotherProgram");`.

Comment: this is not an answer.